# Why is the compiler looking for a copy assignment operator when the move assignment operator is needed?

Tags: c++

```
#include <utility>

class A {
    int* ptr;
public:
    A() {
        ptr = new int[10];
    }

    A(A&& rhs) {
        this->ptr = rhs.ptr;
        rhs.ptr = nullptr;
    }

    ~A() {
        if (ptr) delete[] ptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    A a2;
    a2 = std::move(a1);
}
```

GCC 11 complains that the copy assignment operator is deleted:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:23:22: error: use of deleted function 'constexpr A& A::operator=(const A&)'
   23 |     a2 = std::move(a1);
      |                      ^
<source>:3:7: note: 'constexpr A& A::operator=(const A&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'A' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
    3 | class A {
      |       ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

Then, after I defined the move assignment operator (not copy assignment operator), it compiled fine.  Then, it means compiler is indeed looking for move assignment operator, which I expected.  I don't understand why when the move assignment operator is implicitly deleted, the compiler would look for the copy assignment operator. Any idea?  Or it is just a bad error message from compiler?

Comment: The error message says the copy-assignment-operator is implicitly deleted, not the move-assignment-operator.

Comment: Since you did not define a custom move assignment operator, the compiler will see if it can create one implicitly. [Here are the rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment). (1) There are no user-declared copy constructors - ok. (2) There are no user-declared move constructors - nope, you declared one. Therefore, there is no automatic move assignment operator. Which makes sense: The compiler cannot use the move constructor because it doesn't know what to do with the old value of the object.

Comment: @RaymondChen I agree completely with what you stated.  However, I am trying to understand why the compiler complains about the deleted *copy assignment operator* NOT the deleted *move assignment operator*.  Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured -- the compiler was first looking for `operator=(A&&)` and as @RaymondChen mentioned, it is deleted and so compiler is looking for `operator=(const A&)`, which actually accepts a rvalue as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your explanation is not exactly correct. The compiler wasn't looking particularly for `operator=(A&&)`. It was simply looking for any `operator=` that could be called for that assignment.

Now, the move assignment operator `operator=(A&&)` doesn't exist at all. However, the copy assignment operator `operator=(const A&)` does exist, but it is defined as deleted.

Therefore, the copy assignment operator is the only operator that can be used for that assignment (since constant lvalue references can bind rvalues). The compiler tries to use it but finds out that it is deleted, which triggers that compilation error.